# matplotlib find_peaks I need to ignore spureous peaks

Tags: matplotlib, scipy

I generate a graph like this, it measures the content of a transparent tube but the edges of the tube appear like that, you can see the peaks on the edges of the tube... Any suggestion on how to avoid this "extra" peaks? Any suggestion is welcome.

[image: graph]

The image of the tube is this one

[image: tube]

Comment: The question is not written such that anyone can provide help. You would need to provide the code that you are using to produce this plot as well as a clearer description of the problem.

Comment: just looking for a suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact not a `matplotlib`-specific question. From my understanding of your question, you would like to keep red peaks while remove blue ones. This task can be done by `scipy.signal.find_peaks`, you can specifiy a height value to control the peaks the algorithm finds. Here are some minimum code (adapted from scipy docs):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
x = electrocardiogram()[2000:4000]
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=0.5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
ax.plot(x)
ax.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
ax.axhline(y=0.5, ls="--", color="gray")
```

[image]

Comment: not really, blue ones are the minimum and the red ones maximums, but red ones are considering the edges of the tubes and I dont need that.

Comment: I still dont know what you need from your question.

Comment: I will explain, I do some photo of the tubes like the one I add to the question, the borders of the tube are those pikes in the graph, I ask if somebody could help me on deleting those spikes

Comment: You could do something like ignore peaks that are above a certain distance away from the midpoints between the yellow lines, or ignore a peak if it is too sharp over some interval.